# Error Term Trouble

Tags: numerical-methods

"Consider the approximate formulate: $f'(x) \approx 3/(2h^3) \int_{-h}^{h} tf(x+t) dt$.  Determine its error term."

I was thinking taking the taylor series of $f(x+t)$ to help me actually integrate the integral, but when would I stop the taylor series expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$
F_x(r) = \int_0^r tf(x+t) dt
$$
then via the Taylor formula:
$$
F_x(r) = 0 + 0f(x+0)\times r + A_xr^2 + \frac 16 (2f'(x+0) + 0f''(x+0))r^3 + 
B_xr^4 + O(r^5)
\\=A_xr^2 + \frac 13f'(x)r^3 + B_xr^4 + O(r^5)\\
\frac2{3h^3}\int_{-h}^h tf(x+t)dt = \frac2{3h^3}(F_x(h) - F_x(-h)) 
= f'(x) + O(h^2)\\
$$